# trying to replicate css/javascript of page

Tags: javascript, css

So I'm trying to replicate a page layout, it's an image that is the full height of a page with text to the right of it.  The text width seems to adjust depending on the the image, I'm just not exactly sure how it's done.  http://mcgarrybowen.com/en/People/Bill-Borrelle  that's the page, any thoughts on how this was done?

this is what I tried but isn't quite working right, looks like this  http://www.klossal.com/klossviolins/about.html :

```
<div style="width:100%;padding-top:40px;padding-bottom:40px;">
<div style="width:920px;position:relative;">
    <div style="float:left;">
        <img style="height:100%;" src="http://www.klossal.com/klossviolins/elements/horst.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div style="float:left;">
    <p style="color: #b9b8b4;
      font-family: 'Source Sans Pro' , sans-serif;
      font-size: 24px;
      text-align: left;   
      position:relative;
      width:auto;">About</p>            

    <p style="color: #b9b8b4;
      font-family: 'Source Sans Pro' , sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      text-align: left;      
      position:relative;
      width:auto;">
        Mittenwald-trained, Master Violin Maker, Horst Kloss, has worked with fine stringed instruments and bows for over three decades. The Kloss Shop specializes in the repair, restoration, appraisal and sale of historic instruments and bows. Mr. Kloss further offers acoustic adjustment tailored to the individual musician's requirements, the application of museum conservation standards to preserve instrument integrity and maintain value as well as baroque conversion. Mr. Kloss is experienced in providing musicians with custom instrument set up designed to prevent overuse syndrome while maintaining maximal adjustment of tonal color, clarity and projection.<br><br>

        Since 1972, Horst Kloss has cared for collections of note along the East Coast of the United States, including the Boston Museum of Fine Art's collection of historic stringed instruments. He is one of under a hundred makers, nation-wide, whose extensive training and high caliber skills qualified him for full membership status in the American Federation of Violin and Bow Makers.<br><br>

        Raised among musicians and makers, Horst Kloss was imbued with a love of music and a profound sense of stewardship in caretaking for stringed instruments. At the age of 14, he began an apprenticeship in his hometown of Mittenwald, a center for violin-making since the 1600's. He received his formal training at the Bavarian State School of Violin Making in Southern Germany where he earned his Journeyman's diploma in 1964 and his Master's degree in 1972 under the tutelage of Josef Kantuscher. He moved to the United States in 1964 following the exodus of finer instruments from Europe and gained exposure to many of them while working for Carl Becker at Lewis & Sons. Mr. Kloss instructs the courses offered in instrument repair and restoration at the University of New Hampshire's Violin Craftsmanship Institute. He established shops in Houston and Boston before settling in Needham, Massachusetts.<br><br>

        Horst Kloss has attracted an international clientele, including many distinguished concert performers, who value his consistently high quality restoration and sound adjustments. His experienced eye and broad client base make him especially well-suited to bring buyers and sellers of fine stringed instruments together.</p>
        </div>
        <br class="clear">

</div>
```

Comment: chrome... right-click > inspect element (or press F12)

Answer (score 0):

Just to get you started here is a simple example of how to display the text next to the image:

http://jsfiddle.net/g5wpt/

```
<img class="SomeImage"  src="http://www.klossal.com/klossviolins/elements/horst.jpg" alt="">
<span class="SomeText">Some text next to the image</span>
```

following should go in your css file

```
.SomeImage{
    max-width:80%;/*give some room for your text*/

}
.SomeText{
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Note, the css is in the css class, not inline.  Also, the reason yours isn't working is because you have block elements next to each other which will cause it to wrap to the next line.

Another options is to use a table. http://jsfiddle.net/g5wpt/2/

Comment: so the problem is this is the text starts to move under teh image, and I'd like it to stay in a column, and just get narrower and wider, which would just change the height, like in that example.

Comment: Did you look at this -> http://jsfiddle.net/g5wpt/ the text does not wrap to the next line

Comment: hmm, so when I look at it there is text under the image, but it should all stay to right of the image.

Comment: alright - must be browser related, you can always use a table -> http://jsfiddle.net/g5wpt/2/

Comment: @JustinBicknell IE5/6 don't support this. IE7 and IE8 have bugs regarding max-with/height

Comment: @Tivie - I don't support IE6 you shouldn't either (just joking)

Comment: No but seriously, not many people support IE6 and for good reason

Comment: @JustinBicknell IE6 is not that much relevant today, thank God. I was merely stating a fact. And proposing a solution to his problem that works in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd rather avoid some tricky css, or post run js. I might just suggest using a two-column table if possible.

The table cells will resize themselves based on the content, and it's reliable across all browsers. Because text can be shrunk or grown and the renderer doesn't see it as having a fixed width the fixed width image will push it's cell out and as a result the text cell will become smaller.

The only thing you'll need to do is give the table a width so it fills up the necessary space and not more or less.

Comment: you don't need tricky css or a table. Floating a div and give it 50% of width would work. And will resize accordingly

Comment: I see your `clearfix` in your solution, not to mention when some browsers have different default css on `body` and `html` if those aren't explicitly reset this will ruin the 50% technique. However, at the end of the day I slightly mis-understood what he was going for anyway so my solution isn't as applicable. Yours and Justin's work though.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, to get you started, in this page, when you resize the window, the dude grows and shrinks accordingly (which is kind of creepy if you ask me).

Anyways, they are using javascript to calculate the width of the picture. However, you can aomplish something similar with HTML+CSS alone.

You just need to set the width of the pic container and the text container to 50%.

Here's an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <style>
            #container {
                width: 100%;
            }

            #text {
                width: 48%;
                float: left;                
            }

            #pic-container {
                float: left;
                height: 50%;
            }

            #pic {
                height: 100%;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="pic-container">
                <img id="pic" src="http://mcgarrybowen.com/~/media/A6896FA26F97436E899BCE3307FFC1C2.ashx?as=0"/>
            </div>
            <div id="text">
                Some really cool text lorem ipsum
            </div>
            <div style="clear: both"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```